# How to make self-declaring variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom, javascript-objects

I wan to make a password storing program, and each password is stored into an independant variable, but I'd have to make an infinite number of variables and assign each input value to its corresponding variable.
So is there a way to make Javascript declare the variables by itself and assign it to its corresponding input value?

Comment: how do you remember the name later? why not take an array or object?

Comment: Objects or array might help you.

Comment: you need to assign atleast one static collection veriable

Answer (score 0):

you can use array which can be collection of multiple values.

There will not be any specific limit of array in terms of length.

If you don't know about array, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) Or you can try array online [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Hope this helps, please let me know if you are still not clear.